# Allow autorun from USB drive on Xubuntu

Tags: linux, shell-script, usb-drive

Is there a way I can bypass the popup and automatically run the autorun.sh file quietly?

[image: The PopUp when I insert the USB having the autorun.sh file]

I am currently using Xubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to skip the confirmation prompt offered to the user.

The [Thunar documentation on removable media](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/using-removable-media) discusses the usage of Auto-run and Auto-open functionality. Common to both options is this note (slightly edited):

> As a security precaution, you will **always** be prompted to confirm the
>   auto-run/auto-open.

This behaviour is mandated by the [Desktop Application Autostart Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-0.5.html), which states the following:

For Auto-start files:

> The desktop environment MUST prompt the user for confirmation before
>   automatically starting an application.

For Auto-open files:

> The desktop environment MUST prompt the user for confirmation before
>   opening the file.